# How to loop through userform frames with variable object name

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am attempting to loop the a specific set of frames within each `Multipage` page in my VBA `User_Form`. However, it does not seem like I can use a variable object name with each frame control like I can with the pages.

I am getting an error

> object doesn't support this property or method

at the following line

`For Each cCont in Me.MultiPage1.Pages(PageName).Frames(DataFrame).Controls`

**My Code**

```
Do While x <= Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count
    PageName = "Page" & CStr(x)
    DataFrame = "DataFrame" & CStr(x)
    For Each cCont In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(PageName).Frames(DataFrame).Controls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can't iterate the way you would think you could.

First, you need to iterate through all Pages of your `MultiPage1`.

Second, loop through all `Controls` inside the current `Page` , and check if they are of type `Frame`, if they are you can iterate inside the `Frame` but the syntax is a little different (see in the code below).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub IterateIn_MultiPage()

Dim x As Long, j As Long
Dim cCont As Control

For x = 0 To Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count - 1 ' <-- loop through all MultiPage Pages

    For Each cCont In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(x).Controls ' <-- loop through controls of current page
        If TypeOf cCont Is Frame Then ' <-- check if control type is Frame
            For j = 0 To cCont.Controls.Count - 1   '<-- loop through all items related to the current Frame collection
                MsgBox cCont.Controls(j).Name '<-- display a message box
            Next j
        End If
    Next cCont

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to be working to filter through each checkbox in the frame but adding `If cCont.Controls.Value = True Then` will not work to only find the ones which are checked

Comment: This was not in your post, what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help on putting together the code @Shai, for anyone else wondering what the final code looks like here it is. This loops through each frame within each multipage and pastes the caption of checked checkboxes in my desired range.

```
Option Explicit

Sub IterateIn_MultiPage()
Dim x As Long, j As Long
Dim cCont As Control
Dim counter As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim Range As String
y = 1

For x = 0 To ImportData.MultiPage1.Pages.Count - 1
counter = 0
    For Each cCont In ImportData.MultiPage1.Pages(x).Controls
        Do While counter < 1
            If TypeOf cCont Is Frame Then
                For j = 0 To cCont.Controls.Count - 1
                    If cCont.Controls(j).Value = True Then
                            Range = "E" & y
                            If counter = 0 Then
                                Worksheets("Calculations").Range(Range) = cCont.Controls(j).Caption
                                counter = counter + 1
                            ElseIf counter = 1 Then
                                Worksheets("Calculations").Range(Range) = Worksheets("Calculations").Range(Range) & " & " & cCont.Controls(j).Caption
                                y = y + 1
                            End If
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
        Loop
    Next cCont

Next x

End Sub
```